# Nodejs | npm : html-pdf,set height of the pdf page

Tags: html, node.js, pdf, npm

My code

```
var options = {format:'A3',border:{top:'30px',bottom:'30px',left:'10px'}}
                pdf.create(html,options).toBuffer(function(err, buffer){
                    res.type('application/pdf');
                    res.end(buffer, 'binary');
                });
```

This is always renders the page with a constant height. 
How to set the page height ?
Thanks !

Comment: Refer this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf#options

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to give Header and footer "height" in the options .
This will something like:

```
var options = {format:'A3',header: {  "height": "5mm"},footer: { "height": "5mm"}, border:{top:'30px',bottom:'30px',left:'10px'}}
                pdf.create(html,options).toBuffer(function(err, buffer){
                    res.type('application/pdf');
                    res.end(buffer, 'binary');
                });
```

Comment: How will that help setting the height of the whole page ?
I want to set the height of the page (header, body, footer)
This does not solve my problem.

Comment: You can use page options 
like 
  "height": "10.5in",        // allowed units: mm, cm, in, px
  "width": "8in",

from https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf#options